# Is it possible to create TreeView/DataGrid with style like AltovaXMLSpy?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is it possible to create TreeView/DataGrid with style like AltovaXMLSpy?
I want to create XML browser with control. that looks simmilar to this:

[image: Example of a control]

Was trying to create it as DataGrid, but i dont know how to create  types of dynamic cells:

```
1) Element that contains only Attributes;

2) Element that contains only Nodes;

3) Element that contains Nodes and Attributes;

4) Element that contains Nodes, Attributes and finnaly Grouped Nodes, that will warp into another DataGrid;
```

Comment: With enough code almost anything is possible. You'd be better off with a prebaked control though, for example - https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try this alternate and free version, that pretty much gives what Altova has.
[https://xsemmel.codeplex.com](https://xsemmel.codeplex.com/)